# Adding contacts from Salesforce to All Contact- Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I would like to create an import definition that adds salesforce contacts to mobile connect all contacts when they give their phone number and opt in to text. However, if i use a generic keyword to opt them into can i opt them into other subscription keywords down the road?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A Contact can have multiple MobileConnect SMS keyword subscriptions at once.